# Website identify user without cookies and IP at server side

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, http, cookies

I am currently working on an online shop website by ASP.NET MVC 5 framework, but the following is annoying me

## Requirement & Approach

One of the requirements is the server should assume the cookies feature is disabled at the client side, thus instead of using cookies/session to identify the user, we decided to generate a GUID for each user (if no valid GUID present), append the GUID to every hyper link and use the retrieved GUID as the UID.

## Situation

The system works fine at this point, until we added a verification to it. We would like to avoid Client A steals the GUID from Client B (it would be easy because the GUID is visible in the URL and SSL can do nothing about it), then the Client A add items to the shopping cart with Client B GUID, and wait till Client B pay for it (please ignore if the Client B review the cart or the shipping address).

## Problem

What we have done to avoid the above hack is adding some information from the HTTP request header such as user IP, user agent, accepting languages etc... We verify the information on every request, treat the GUID as invalid if any info is changed.

The problem is we found out some of our ISPs in our region will send every request by a different IP, thus the user will gain a different GUID on every page/request.

It seems not so secure without the IP as a part of the identifier, we are looking for some other workaround to secure our clients, I have done on some researches and the followings are some possibly solutions:

- Using ETAG, however I am not quite understand but it seems not quite suitable for our project (in the MVC action we can only know if this is the first visit from the client of the requesting page, if a valid client visit a new page such as ConfirmOrder will be treated as invalid)
- Using the basic authorization by including the identity information in the request header, however in order to increase the user experience, we wish not to ask the user to input a username/pwd, but it seems we cannot assign a default identity from server side.

Any solution/suggestion/clues will be welcome, thanks for your time

Answer (score -1):

Could you use cookies and only fallback to GUID + hard verification if cookies fail?

Alternatively you could do every request as an AJAX request and just replace the entiere page with the answer and update the URL (minus the GUID) via `history.pushState()`. This is also known as PJAX. But when cookies aren't allowed JavaScript is probably blocked as well.

I've also seen applications do every request as a POST, thus hiding every parameter. But that also makes page reloads or navigating via the back button harder for the user.

Comment: Hi Björn, I prefer not to use the fallback approach since we assume all the clients have disabled the cookies feature. We do require JavaScript to visit the site but the PJAX solution still expose the GUID after the first page (from the 2nd page every link will be appended the GUID). For the POST part we agree with the big effort of the back button for the user. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: You don't have to show the GUID to the user with the PJAX solution. You just have to save it to a JavaScript variable (or localstorage, which would be quite similar to cookies) and append it to the links in your AJAX calls. You could also use JavaScript to remove the GUID from all links on the page if you can't do it server-side.

Comment: Sorry but we have a set of log that is embed into each page (to study user behavior etc.) and each log uses the GUID as the filename.